# Products not showing up when disabled on All Store Views and enabled on Specific Store View

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I've setup a Multistore in Magento 2.1.x
I've placed some products in the stores.

When I create a product I will set enabled to "No". 
(This is because there are products that only apply to 1 language, and in the future there will be like 10 languages. So it's easier to enable on specific store views than disable them on specific store views.)
[image]
After I save the product, I click it once again so I can select a specific store view.
When I've selected the specific store view I will enable the product.
[image]
After re-indexation the product won't show up. (I've cache disabled)
The product shows when I set enabled to yes on "All Store Views", so the configuration of the product is ok.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried:  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ?

Comment: Yes, tried that. Re-indexed afterwards still same result..

Comment: When I set both store views to Enable Product "Yes" the product will show on the frontend. But when I set Enable Product "No" on one of the store views it won't show on both....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the scope of the Enable Product attribute, because it is set to "Website" instead of "Store View".

Source: Magento Manual "The Product Status has a Website scope, meaning that you can hide or show a product per Website, affecting all store views for that Website."

Solution #1 (Dirty):
Set product visibility to "Not Visible Individually" on specific store view.

Solution #2 (Recommended):
Create extra website instead of store view.